# switch for AC voltage

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac, triac

I am designing a switch for AC circuit. E.g. when I apply a small DC voltage, AC current is allowed to conduct, otherwise there is huge resitance stop the current from flowing.

I found 2 possible solutions on the web. TRIAC or 2 opposite MOSFET in series. But the problem is: the AC voltage is floating, it is not grounded. Its a AC wave produced from H bridge from another DC source. (which use the same ground as the small DC voltage to control the AC current). E.g. I cannot define the gate voltage correctly.

Does anyone know how to achieve the control? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your 2nd circuit shows an opto-photo-voltaic device and this is usually resiliant in your sort of application.

Comment: If you don't need a high-frequency switch, a conventional mechanical relay will work.

Comment: A Solid State Relay(SSR) will also work too if you want the opto-isolation.

Comment: @andyaka Does that means I need to place a LED (to my DC voltage) and sensor(grounded to AC) in my circuit?

Comment: @PeterBennett The AC is 200kHz. How does that sound?

Comment: @Axis This device you mentioned seems quite ideal for my application actually (4 pin which allow differential input). But the only problem is the rated current is a bit small. I can only find 1A rated, which is not very sufficient for my particular application. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: @yuhao Yes search digikey for a chassis mount package(Some are rated up to 160A): http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv69=885&FV=fff40010%2Cfff80058&k=SSR&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: @yuhao I added SSRs as an answer.

Comment: @yuhao - I notice that you say the AC is 200 kHz. This makes a **massive** difference to what technology can be used. Please edit your question to make it clear that your AC is 200 kHz.

Comment: My relay suggestion will work if it is only switched ocassionally - switching the circuit off or on.  It won't switch at 200 KHz, but will carry 200 KHz when the contacts are closed.

Answer (score 2):

When I need to switch an AC load the first thing I do is look for an appropriate SSR. They are easy to use and pretty robust. They switch from a low voltage DC source and generally only take a few milliamps to turn on. Another bonus is that they come in a tons of packages ranging from tens of milliamps to hundreds of amps. [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/relays/solid-state-relays/1048664?k=SSR) has a wide selection of SSR to choose from. If you are looking for high current ones I suggest filtering the product search for chassis mount packages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need another circuit to control your H-Bridge? Simply control each of the 4 transistors individually, and when you want to break the current flow, switch one of the conducting pair off.

Now if you don't have access to the H-Bridge because you're using someone else's magic, then I would suggest your second circuit with one addition. The circuit you have show has a great turn on time, but a *horrible* turn off time. Add an opto-coupled transistors like the diagram below to speed up turn off time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX4sic.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I do have control over H bridge. But The switch here has something to do with load modulation rather then turn the whole H bridge output down.May I ask what is necessary about Q1 Q2 on your diagram compare to the simple one I used as my 2nd diagram in the question?

Comment: Q1 and Q2 allow you to use 1 GPIO output to control the mosfets. The optocoupled transistor forced the charge stored on the mosfets back to ground (that center node) turning them off faster than if you just "stopped making current" through the photovoltaic. You could use 2 GPIO, and two less transistors, but then you'd need code to guarantee turn off speed.